# Converting ArrayList to 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, arraylist

After figuring out a way pof create of list of random numbers from 1 to 16, how can I display this list in matrix form.

```
 public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}
System.out.println(list); //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
Collections.shuffle(list);
System.out.println(list); //[11, 5, 10, 9, 7, 0, 6, 1, 3, 14, 2, 4, 15, 13, 12, 8]

int[][] a2 = new int[4][4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0;  j< 4; j++) {


        a2[i][j] = list.get(i*4 + j);
      //  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a2)); //[[11, 5, 10, 9], [7, 0, 6, 1],     [3, 14, 2, 4], [15, 13, 12, 8]]
    }
   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a2)); //[[11, 5, 10, 9], [7, 0, 6, 1], [3,     14, 2, 4], [15, 13, 12, 8]]
}
//System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a2)); //[[11, 5, 10, 9], [7, 0, 6, 1], [3, 14                  2, 4], [15, 13, 12, 8]]
}
```

Like this :
    3, 4, 5, 8,
    2, 6, 7, 9,
    11, 1, 15, 13,
    10, 12, 14, 0

I put a zero at the end because I want it to present a void that can be moved by the user, using boolean operators.

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, please tag it as such. And what is the problem you are having?

Comment: I'm trying to create a matrix of random numbers, I was told to use ArryList but this only prints in a line. I wanted to use Random but Random repeats and I dont want that. So I uses ArrayList and now I want to break it to look like a matrix.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I replied you. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Your two for-loops breaks the list into a 2D array just fine.

To *print* the `a2` matrix you could for instance do the following:

```
for (int[] row : a2) {
    System.out.print("[");
    for (int i : row)
        System.out.printf("%4d", i);
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

Result:

```
[   6  11   3   7]
[   4  14   5   9]
[   2  13  16  10]
[   8   1  12  15]
```

Comment: It doesn't break it into a matrix.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by matrix? @aioobe print out does seem like one.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I want. But what does for (int i : row)
        System.out.printf("%4d", i); mean?

Comment: for (int i : row) is a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and printf is a way to [printing a formatted a string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
int index = 1;
for(Integer i : list) {
  System.out.print(i);
  if (index % 4 == 0)
    System.out.println();
  index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need ArrayList and Random, then you can use the following:

```
Random random = new Random();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j=0;j<4;j++) {
        array.add(random.nextInt(16)+1);
    }
    matrix.add(array);
}
```

And then you can simply iterate over the matrix and print each array.

```
for(ArrayList<Integer> array: matrix) {
    System.out.println(array);
}
```

Comment: 'ArrayList<Integer> array = new Array();' doesn't work for me. It telle=s me to import java.sql.Array

Comment: I added List to the end of "Array", it ran but numbers were repeated.